# property 'length' of undefined - React tutorial

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-native, okta

I'm following a react tutorial, but there is an error that does not let me continue, I've tried everything and nothing, it's giving undefined, but I already changed several things and I could not solve.

[image: erro]

**Code:**

```
class PostsManager extends Component {
  state = {
    loading: true,
    posts: [],
  };

  componentDidMount() {
    this.getPosts();
  }

  async fetch(method, endpoint, body) {
    try {
      const response = await fetch(`${API}${endpoint}`, {
        method,
        body: body && JSON.stringify(body),
        headers: {
          'content-type': 'application/json',
          accept: 'application/json',
          authorization: `Bearer ${await this.props.auth.getAccessToken()}`,
        },
      });
      return await response.json();
    } catch (error) {
      console.error(error);
    }
  }

  async getPosts() {
    this.setState({ loading: false, posts: await this.fetch('get', '/posts') });
  }

  async deletePost(post) {
    if (window.confirm(`Are you sure you want to delete "${post.title}"`)) {
      await this.fetch('delete', `/posts/${post.id}`);
      this.getPosts();
    }
  }
    return (
      <Fragment>
        <Typography variant="display1">Posts Manager</Typography>
        {this.state.posts.length > 0 ? (
          <Paper elevation={1} className={classes.posts}>
            <List>
           ....
```

Comment: Your return doesn't even seem to be in a method. Please give a [mcve].

Answer (score 1):

Agree with Glup3 but I would just use `this.state.posts.length` instead of checking if the length is greater than 0. This way, if .length is undefined or 0, it will be falsey.

```
{this.state.posts.length ? ....
```

Answer (score 0):

Assuming `this.fetch('get', '/posts')` works and returns some json you'd need to actually evaluate the response:

```
async getPosts() {
    const response = await this.fetch('get', '/posts');
    const json = await response.json();
    this.setState({ loading: false, posts: json });
 }
```

More information [here](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Fetch_API/Using_Fetch) at mdn.

Answer (score 0):

You want to render `<Fragment>...</Fragment>` but you get an error. It is because `this.state.posts` is null/undefined and length can't be used on such.

Solution: Make a if condition and wait until it's not null anymore.

```js
if (this.state.posts != null) {
  return (<Fragment> ... </Fragment>);
}
else {
  return (<div> Loading... </div>); // or something else
}
```

Yours Glup3